# Is Hubbard& Hubbard good for learning analysis?

Tags: analysis, reference-request

I am currently using that book for learning multivariable calculus and linear algebra and I am really liking it.

The author said on preface that this book could be used in a course of analysis by using appendix, but since I haven't had anybody who had experiences with appendices I want to ask how good they are for learning analysis. Like, are they in par with Spivak, Munkres or other books dedicated to multivariable analysis alone.

Thanks in advance.

Also any other books on multivariable analysis, preferabley ones with good proof of IFT are welcome

Comment: IFT = Inverse Fourier Transform ???